# Test significance of combined interaction coefficients

Tags: r, statistical-significance, interaction, panel-data

Is there a way to test the significance of combined (interaction) coefficients in R?

I have a panel regression model of the following (simplified) form:

> y<sub>i,t</sub> = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>x<sub>i,t</sub> + b<sub>2</sub>x<sub>i,t</sub>*phase_1<sub>t</sub>+ b<sub>3</sub>x<sub>i,t</sub>*phase_2<sub>t</sub> + l<sub>i</sub> + k<sub>t</sub> + e<sub>i,t</sub>

where phase_1<sub>t</sub> and phase_2<sub>t</sub> are dummy variables equal to 1 in a non-overlapping subset of T.
Hence, b<sub>1</sub> captures the effect of x in Phase 0, b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub> the effect in Phase 1 and  b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>3</sub> the effect in Phase 2.

The results are a weakly significant positive effect of b<sub>1</sub> and a significant negative effect of b<sub>2</sub>. b<sub>3</sub> is negative but insignificant. How can I know if the combined effect of b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>3</sub> is significantly positive (or negative)? (i.e. does x have a significant positive/ negative effect in Phase 2?) I guess estimating the model without the b<sub>3</sub> would be problematic, as b<sub>1</sub> would then capture the effect of x in Phase 0 **and** Phase 2.

I currently estimate the model using the plm function with time (t) and country (i) fixed effects and interpret coefficients clustered at the country level.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by just changing the coding of the dummy variables.
That is, I code a dummy phase_0 instead of phase_2. The baseline coefficient now captures the total effect of x in Phase 2. The same approach would work for Phase 1.